# Can you make a "text-box" using PIL?

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library

I want to make an bot that, when it reads a string input, draws that text on an image, but I want to make sure the image stays inside a "box", inside certain coordinates of the image, say (0,0) - (500,500).

I tried to cut the string every 10 characters and make a new line but that would make many lines if someone spams characters, so I thought I'd make the font smaller when that would happen but I have no idea on how to start this and how I would make it efficient.

I am using PIL, but I read their documentation and I didn't see a way to make a "text-box", is there any way to do this easier?

Comment: Maybe you could give a couple of examples of how you envisage it working....

Comment: With PIL you can add text to an image by giving it coordinates and the library puts the coordinates and the text you input on the image, but if I input a long string the text goes outside of the image. I want the text, when it reaches the edge of the image to go "hit return" and change line, go below. How could I do that?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using **wand** for that. Perfect example here... http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.8/guide/draw.html#texts

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll look into it.